# How do I download all files from S3 bucket that was uploaded on a specific date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket that may have millions of files. These are files created by CloudTrail (CloudTrail logs). I want to write a python script that will download only those files that were uploaded on a specific date. I already have the download code working -- that is not the issue. The issue is how to specifically download only those subset of files that were created/uploaded on a specific date?

This seems like a pretty straight-forward use case and I'm amazed that S3 APIs do not support this.

Comment: AWS CLI for S3 can download subset of files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 'last modified date' property of S3 objects to filter them based on a specific date. Here is an example using Java API:

```
ObjectListing listing = s3Client.listObjects('my_bucket_name');
List<S3ObjectSummary> objectSummaries = listing.getObjectSummaries();

for(S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary: objectSummaries) {
   if(s3ObjectSummary.getLastModified().equals(today) {
     //download this file
     s3Client.getObject('my_bucket_name', s3ObjectSummary.getKey());
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was thinking the same but this would list all the objects from S3. The bucket may contain  large number of files (in the order of few hundred-thousand at least). How would this be performant?

Comment: You can list only up to 1,000 objects per 'listObjects()' API call (so you have to do the above in a loop to get all the objects). So yes, there is a performance hit . You can check out this thread which discusses a similar problem (and some workarounds - I like the workaround of using the date prefix for keys ) : https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1104.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! Appreciate it.